# Redux toolkit useSelector return undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state, redux-toolkit

when I log in I dispatch the login, setUserToken, setUserData reducer functions and I console.log them and I see that their state has been updated as intended.
but when I try to receive the data back for later use it is undefined/false.

**configure redux store**
**store.js**

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import authReducer from "./auth";

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        auth: authReducer,
    },
});

export default store;
```

**Create slice**
**auth.js**

```
import {createSlice} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";


//create variable that we want redux to store for us
//this object configure the redux "state"
const initialAuthState = {
    loggedIn: false,
    userToken: "",
    userData: []
};

const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: "auth",
    initialState: initialAuthState,

    reducers: {
        login(state) {
            state.loggedIn = true;
            // console.log("login state: ", state.loggedIn)
        },
        setToken(state, action) {
            state.userToken = action.payload;
            // console.log("state.userToken: ", state.userToken)
        },
        setUserInfo(state, action) {
            state.userData = action.payload;
            // console.log("state.userData: ", state.userData)
        },

        logout(state) {
            state.loggedIn = initialAuthState.loggedIn;
            state.userToken = initialAuthState.userToken;
            state.userData = initialAuthState.userData;
        },

    },
});

export const authActions = authSlice.actions;

export default authSlice.reducer;
```

**using the state**
**Hompage.jsx**

```
import {Container} from "../helpers/Container";
import {Title} from "../helpers/Title";
import {useSelector} from "react-redux";
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

import store from "../../store/store";

function Homepage() {
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState([])
    let loggedin = useSelector((state) => state?.auth?.loggedIn);
    let user = useSelector((state) => state?.auth?.userData);
    let userTk = useSelector((state) => state?.auth?.userToken);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("user: ", user)  // undefined
        console.log("userTk: ", userTk) // undefined
        console.log("loggedin: ", loggedin) // false
        setUserData(user)
    }, [])
    return (
        <Container>
            <div>-{user}-{userTk}-{loggedin}</div>
            <Title titleText={"Welcome"} user={userData?.userName}/>
        </Container>
    );
}

export default Homepage;
```

i tried to display the user name in the hmepage to greet the user after login.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly export the actions from the slice

```
export const { login, setToken, setUserInfo, logout } = authSlice.actions
```

Something like this.

Comment: i tried your answer and it didnt fix the problem. thanks for your effort.
link to image of the output:
https://ibb.co/C2zffy1

Comment: I don't see any problem in this image because now when you console log them they are no longer undefined right. The only thing that's left I assume is for you to set the user info so you can show it on screen.

Comment: your right they are not undefined but the state's value is not as should be.
they have been not undefined before that but I cant receive the state data/value.
or might be I don't update the state properly?
when i console.log the state on dispatch the data is there.
 
link to image showing the value of the state after dispatching:
https://ibb.co/fDT99XV

Comment: I see maybe I'm the one who is lost, is it possible to see your full code maybe a github repo?

Comment: i havent merged the branch yet sience the problem is not solved.

Comment: That's bad we were gonna look at the problem together it would be easier that way

Comment: i think i know what is the issue.
redux doenst save the state after refresh.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out.